# populating html table with mySQL data in php without adding duplicate rows

Tags: php, pdo, duplicates

I use this query to get data from 3 different tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM locatie_regel 
        INNER JOIN locatie ON locatie_regel.locatie_id = locatie.locatie_id
        INNER JOIN product ON locatie_regel.product_id = product.product_id";

$query = $pdo->query($sql);

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

This now returns 7 objects like it should. I want these objects as rows in a html table. I did this like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $result->product_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->product; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $result->type; ?></td>

    <td><?php if($result->locatie_id == 1){ echo $result->aantal; }else{ echo ''; } ?></td>
    <td><?php if($result->locatie_id == 2){ echo $result->aantal; }else{ echo ''; } ?></td>
    <td><?php if($result->locatie_id == 3){ echo $result->aantal; }else{ echo ''; } ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

That all works fine but when you look at the output:
[image]

This is exactly what I did above but what I want to achieve is that there is only 1 row per product id. I have been trying to find a solution for a few hours now but I didn't find any.

I am probably thinking way to hard on this and I guess I should use another query or something, but it would be nice if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean, you don't want duplicates? If so, add `DISTINCT` to your query and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: hmm I will try that now, exuse my ignorance, have not been using php for a long time (:

Comment: Not a problem, *cheers* - In doing so, you won't have to restructure the rest of your code.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom eventually put a unique key on product id field

Comment: @MarcoMura product id has a unique key, that is not the problem ;)

Comment: sorry @GoosvandenBekerom, i vote for Fred solution of distinct ;)

Comment: no problem ;) right now im just trying to figure out how it works :P

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT FROM locatie_regel...` then `GROUP BY product_id` - Have a look at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: You're welcome. Would you like me to post it as an answer in order to close the question?

Comment: please do, Maybe you could add to the answer how I would change my query, because when I do this i do only get 3 rows but only with data under rotterdam (if that makes sence)

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom Ah, might be related to the JOINs then. I couldn't put in an answer if I can't solve that part. I'm not very good with joins. Or just try removing the `GROUP BY` while keeping `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same, but that didn't work, If I only use distinct nothing happens, and with group by that happens

Comment: Ok, then try removing `DISTINCT` and just use `GROUP BY` while using `SELECT * ...`

Comment: that is what i have now, but then it does that thing that only rotterdam has values. should we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66588/discussion-between-goos-van-den-bekerom-and-fred-ii).

Comment: `ON locatie_regel.product_id = product.product_id GROUP BY product.product_id";` or `ON locatie_regel.product_id = product.product_id GROUP BY product_id";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- After struggling with it a bit more I found out that Distinct and Group by were not going to work with my database stucture, I can't change the structure though, because it is a normalized database based on a few receipts. so LavaSliders answer worked for me. thanks a lot for your help and time though, did learn a lot from it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is giving you what you have asked for. Your database has separate entries for the locations and that is why you are getting separate rows in your table. You could change your schema so that you have three fields in **product** table, one for the information at each location or modify your code to deal with it.

A possibility for fixing the code is:

```
<?php
$product_id = NULL;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if( $result->product_id != $product_id ) {
        if( !is_null( $product_id ) ) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $locate_1_aantal; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $locate_2_aantal; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $locate_3_aantal; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        }
        $product_id = $result->product_id;
        $product = $result->product;
        $type = $result->type;
        $locate_1_aantal = '';
        $locate_2_aantal = '';
        $locate_3_aantal = '';
    }
    switch( $result->locate_id ) {
        case 1:
                $locate_1_aantal = $result->aantal;
                break;
        case 2:
                $locate_2_aantal = $result->aantal;
                break;
        case 3:
                $locate_3_aantal = $result->aantal;
                break;
    }
}
if( !is_null( $product_id ) ) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $locate_1_aantal; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $locate_2_aantal; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $locate_3_aantal; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would probable break the writing of the table line out into a separate function so I did not need to repeat the code but I think you get the idea.

Comment: when I was reading this a few days ago I couldn't get my head around it, and still as I read it I don't really get how it works, but it works exactly as it needs to, thanks a lot! Could you maybe explain briefly how it stays on the same row within a foreach loop?

Comment: It basically does not output anything until the **product_id** changes. That gives the foreach loop enough time to have gone through all the **locatie_id**s. It does depend on the results being sorted by **product_id** so that you are guaranteed to not get the location information for one product, then location information for another product, the location information for the first product. So, when a new **product_id** is encountered, it outputs all the accumulated information from the previous one, resets, and starts accumulating for the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some much more complicated than what you've got:

```
$previd = null;
foreach ($results as $result) {
   if ($result->id != $previd) {
       #output previous built data...
       echo "<td>$product</td><td>$type</td>etc...";

       #end previous row/start new row
       echo "</tr><tr><td>" . $result->id . "</td>";

       # Reset vars to empty
       $product = $type = $rotterdam = etc... = '';


       $previd = $result->id;
   }
   $product .= $result->product . "\n";
   $type .= $result->type . "\n";
   etc...
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, and have been thinking about something like this today but couldn't figure it out. +1 for now, though I feel like @Fred's comment will do the job, if it won't I will use this. Thank you very much at least!